# NIFs raise Segmentation Fault while loading function has try catch block to handle the exception

Tags: c++, erlang-nif

I am working on integrating a C++ api with Elixir, by using NIFs. Now whenever I load the NIF, I want to initialize some variables/data which will be persisted across NIF calls. I was trying to achieve the same by `load` function mentioned in the `ERL_NIF_INIT` call. But I am observing some weird behavior out of load function. Please have a look at the below mentioned example and then I’ll explain the issue further:

```
#include <erl_nif.h>

static ERL_NIF_TERM sample(ErlNifEnv *env, int argc, const ERL_NIF_TERM argv[]) {
  return enif_make_atom(env, "ok");
}

static ErlNifFunc nif_funcs[] = {{"sample", 1, sample}};

static int load(ErlNifEnv *env, void **priv_data, ERL_NIF_TERM load_info) {
  try {
    1 / 0; // nif loads if this is the case
    int x = 1 / 0; // float point exception segmentation fault when used this line
  } catch (...) {
    return 1;
  }
  return 0;
}

ERL_NIF_INIT(Elixir.Sample, nif_funcs, load, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

Now closely observe the `load` function containing the `try/catch` block, when I use `1 / 0;` expression in the body of `try` block, NIF is loaded but when the expression `1 / 0;` is replaced by `int x = 1 / 0;` erlang vm fails to load NIF and crashes with `floating point exception segmentation fault` even if I have added the `try/catch` block to handle the exception. Can someone explain this to me? I really need help here.

Here is the elixir code used for interfacing:

```
defmodule Sample do
  @on_load :load_nifs

  def load_nifs do
    :ok =
      :sample
      |> :code.priv_dir()
      |> Path.join("sample")
      |> :erlang.load_nif("0.0.1")
  end

  def sample(_) do
    raise "sample/1 Function not implemented"
  end
end
```

Command used to compile NIF `g++ -fPIC -shared sample.cpp -o sample.so`

P.S. - Thanks for your time to read this, I really appreciate it.

Comment: The explanation is simple -- dividing by zero is not a C++ exception.  You have to check this the old-fashioned way by testing the denominator.

Comment: Ah I see! Also If that's the case then why `1 / 0;` expression works when it is not assigned to any variable? Is it because of compiler removing the statement as it's output is not used anywhere in one of those code optimization steps?

Comment: Even if you were to assign it to a variable, it still will not generate a C++ exception.  Maybe some other system level or OS exception, but not a C++ exception.  The C++ language specification lists where the C++ language must throw an exception for certain conditions (`std::vector<T>::at()`, for example).  Dividing by zero is not one of those conditions that throws a C++ exception.